# Concept - Distilling how a promise works?

Tags: javascript

I've looked at many implementations and they all look so different I can't really distill what the essence of a promise is.

If I had to guess it is just a function that runs when a callback fires.

Can someone implement the most basic promise in a few lines of code w/ out chaining.

For example from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643450/designing-a-queue-system-for-asynchronous-resources)

**Snippet 1**

```
var a1 = getPromiseForAjaxResult(ressource1url);
a1.then(function(res) {
    append(res);
    return a2;
});
```

How does the function passed to `then` know when to run.

That is, how is it passed back to the callback code that ajax fires on completion.

**Snippet 2**

```
// generic ajax call with configuration information and callback function
ajax(config_info, function() {
    // ajax completed, callback is firing.
});
```

How are these two snippets related?

**Guess:**

```
// how to implement this

(function () {
    var publik = {};
        _private;
    publik.then = function(func){
        _private = func;
    };
    publik.getPromise = function(func){
        // ??
    };
    // ??
}())
```

Comment: follow up to ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643450/designing-a-queue-system-for-asynchronous-resources

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Can someone implement the most basic promise in a few lines?

Here it is:

```
function Promise(exec) {
    // takes a function as an argument that gets the fullfiller
    var callbacks = [], result;
    exec(function fulfill() {
        if (result) return;
        result = arguments;
        for (let c;c=callbacks.shift();)
            c.apply(null, arguments);
    });
    this.addCallback = function(c) {
        if (result)
            c.apply(null, result)
        else
            callbacks.push(c);
    }
}
```

Additional `then` with chaining (which you will need for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15643799/1048572)):

```
Promise.prototype.then = function(fn) {
    return new Promise(fulfill => {
        this.addCallback((...args) => {
            const result = fn(...args);
            if (result instanceof Promise)
                result.addCallback(fulfill);
            else
                fulfill(result);
        });
    });
};
```

<sup>Disclaimer: the code is lacking [error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21616432/1048572) (an error state, providing a `reject` function, and using `try`/`catch` around `exec(…)` and `fn(…)`), doing [recursive `resolve(…)` instead of `fulfill(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269515/1048572) (for thenables), and [guaranteed consistent asynchrony](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932244/1048572) (of `then` callbacks) - but adding those does not really change the basic concept.</sup>

> How are these two snippets related?

`ajax` is called from the `getPromiseForAjaxResult` function:

```
function getPromiseForAjaxResult(ressource) {
    return new Promise(function(callback) {
        ajax({url:ressource}, callback);
    });
}
```

Comment: both implementations are wildly different.

Comment: …but their principle is the same. Is there something you don't understand, the code is quite straightforward?

Comment: Promises have two big differences from Events/PubSub: One promise represents exactly one value (which may arrive in the future), and you can add callbacks whenever you want - they will get executed with the value even if it has already arrived. You might also want to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises

Comment: I thought that Promise was a class, not a function, and that you created a Promise by "new Promise" or by calling a function that does "new Promise". Am I right or wrong?

Comment: @DavidSpector Yes, it's a class, you cannot omit `new`. But notice that constructors can be defined with `function` as well, and that this answer was written way before ES6 `class` syntax and native `Promise`s became a standard. The above implementation demonstrates the *concept*, it's not a polyfill (lacking complete error handling, for example).

Answer (score 27):

Fundamentally, a promise is just an object that has a flag saying whether it's been settled, and a list of functions it maintains to notify if/when it is settled. Code can sometimes say more than words, so here's a **very basic, not-real-world** example purely indended to help communicate the concepts:

```
// See notes following the code for why this isn't real-world code
function Promise() {
    this.settled = false;
    this.settledValue = null;
    this.callbacks = [];
}
Promise.prototype.then = function(f) {
    if (this.settled) {
        f(this.settledValue);                // See notes 1 and 2
    } else {
        this.callbacks.push(f);
    }
                                             // See note 3 about `then`
                                             // needing a return value
};
Promise.prototype.settle = function(value) { // See notes 4 and 5
    var callback;

    if (!this.settled) {
        this.settled = true;
        this.settledValue = value;
        while (this.callbacks.length) {
            callback = this.callbacks.pop();
            callback(this.settledValue);      // See notes 1 and 2
        }
    }
};
```

So the `Promise` holds the state, and the functions to call when the promise is settled. The act of *settling* the promise is usually external to the `Promise` object itself (although of course, that depends on the actual use, you might combine them — for instance, as with jQuery's `ajax` [`jqXHR`] objects).

Again, the above is purely conceptual and missing several important things that must be present in any real-world promises implementation for it to be useful:

1. `then` and `settle` should *always* call the callback asynchronously, even if the promise is already settled. `then` should because otherwise the caller has no idea whether the callback will be async. `settle` should because the callbacks shouldn't run until after `settle` has returned. (ES2015's promises do both of these things. jQuery's `Deferred` doesn't.)
2. `then` and `settle` should ensure that failure in the callback (e.g., an exception) is not propagated directly to the code calling `then` or `settle`. This is partially related to #1 above, and more so to #3 below.
3. `then` should return a *new* promise based on the result of calling the callback (then, or later). This is fairly fundamental to composing promise-ified operations, but would have complicated the above markedly. Any reasonable promises implementation does.
4. We need different types of "settle" operation: "resolve" (the underlying action succeeded) and "reject" (it failed). Some use cases might have more states, but resolved and rejected are the basic two. (ES2015's promises have resolve and reject.)
5. We might make `settle` (or the separate `resolve` and `reject`) private in some way, so that only the creator of the promise can settle it. (ES2015 promises — and several others — do this by having the `Promise` constructor accept a callback that receives `resolve` and `reject` as parameter values, so only code in that callback can resolve or reject [unless code in the callback makes them public in some way].)

Etc., etc.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical The code making the promise also calls its `fulfill` method when it's done.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical: Whatever it is that fulfills the promise; usually (as Waleed says above), the thing creating the promise. This is one of the great things about promises: They decouple the promise interface from the specifics of the promise generator.

Comment: Best quote: `f(this)` Literate programming?

Comment: @livingston_mechanical if you're talking about a library's AJAX function (like jQuery), it's already built to use promises. If you make your own AJAX function, then what you would do is make a promise object inside of the AJAX function, and return that promise to the outside (for chaining, or for saving to a variable), and then you would give `.onload` and `.onerror` references to `.fulfill` or `.lapse` or whatever your "keep promise" and "break promise" are called.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical: *"So in the example of an ajax call, how will the ajax call get access to the Promise object in order to call fulfill?"* You receive the promise *from* the `ajax` call, so it just keeps a copy so it can call the `fulfill` method on it.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical: Right: Something will call `fulfill`, and that will trigger the callback. Out of curiousity, what was it about the other answer that made you think it was more acceptable than this one? It's **totally** up to you what answer you do or don't accept (and please don't change it), don't get me wrong, I'm just curious.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical: Doh! Originally I'd called the flag `satisfied`, then decided it should be `fulfilled`, and did a search-and-replace -- but I'd misspelled `satisfied` in the `fulfill` function so it didn't get updated! Fixed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can this `while (this.callbacks.length) {
            callback = this.callbacks.pop();
            callback(this.settledValue);      // See notes 1 and 2
        }` be written into more simplier term as `this.callbacks[0](this.settledValue); this.callbacks.shift()`  without the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

I've implement one in ES7. With chaining, it's 70 lines, if that counts as few. I think State Machine is the right paradigm for implementing promises. Resulting code is more understandable than lots of `if`s IMHO. Described fully in [this article](https://hackernoon.com/implementing-javascript-promise-in-70-lines-of-code-b3592565af0f).

Here's the code:

```
const states = {
    pending: 'Pending',
    resolved: 'Resolved',
    rejected: 'Rejected'
};

class Nancy {
    constructor(executor) {
        const tryCall = callback => Nancy.try(() => callback(this.value));
        const laterCalls = [];
        const callLater = getMember => callback => new Nancy(resolve => laterCalls.push(() => resolve(getMember()(callback))));
        const members = {
            [states.resolved]: {
                state: states.resolved,
                then: tryCall,
                catch: _ => this
            },
            [states.rejected]: {
                state: states.rejected,
                then: _ => this,
                catch: tryCall
            },
            [states.pending]: {
                state: states.pending,
                then: callLater(() => this.then),
                catch: callLater(() => this.catch)
            }
        };
        const changeState = state => Object.assign(this, members[state]);
        const apply = (value, state) => {
            if (this.state === states.pending) {
                this.value = value;
                changeState(state);
                for (const laterCall of laterCalls) {
                    laterCall();
                }
            }
        };

        const getCallback = state => value => {
            if (value instanceof Nancy && state === states.resolved) {
                value.then(value => apply(value, states.resolved));
                value.catch(value => apply(value, states.rejected));
            } else {
                apply(value, state);
            }
        };

        const resolve = getCallback(states.resolved);
        const reject = getCallback(states.rejected);
        changeState(states.pending);
        try {
            executor(resolve, reject);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    }

    static resolve(value) {
        return new Nancy(resolve => resolve(value));
    }

    static reject(value) {
        return new Nancy((_, reject) => reject(value));
    }

    static try(callback) {
        return new Nancy(resolve => resolve(callback()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a light-weight promise implementation, called 'sequence', which I use in my day-to-day work:

```
(function() {
    sequence = (function() {
        var chained = [];
        var value;
        var error;

        var chain = function(func) {
            chained.push(func);
            return this;
        };

        var execute = function(index) {
            var callback;
            index = typeof index === "number" ? index : 0;

            if ( index >= chained.length ) {
                chained = [];
                return true;
            }

            callback = chained[index];

            callback({
                resolve: function(_value) {
                    value = _value;
                    execute(++index);
                },
                reject: function(_error) {
                    error = _error;
                    execute(++index);
                },
                response: {
                    value: value,
                    error: error
                }
            });
        };

        return {
            chain: chain,
            execute: execute
        };
    })();
})();
```

Once initialized, you can use sequence in the following way:

```
sequence()
    .chain(function(seq) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("func A");
            seq.resolve();
        }, 2000);
    })
    .chain(function(seq) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("func B");
        }, 1000)
    })
    .execute()
```

To enable the actual chaining, you need to call the resolve() function of the seq object, which your callbacks must use as an argument.

Sequence exposes two public methods:

- chain - this method simply pushes your callbacks to a private array
- execute - this method uses recursion to enable the proper sequential execution of your callbacks. It basically executes your callbacks in the order you've chained them by passing the seq object to each of them. Once the current callback is resolved/rejected, the next callback is executed.

The 'execute' method is where the magic happens. It passes the 'seq' object to all of your callbacks. So when you call seq.resolve() or seq.reject() you'll actually call the next chained callback.

Please, note that this implementation stores a response from only the previously executed callback.

For more examples and documentation, please refer to:
https://github.com/nevendyulgerov/sequence

Comment: Please explain how this is better than Promise. I don't see it.

Comment: @DavidSpector It's not a promise, lacking all the core characteristics. It's just a lazy callback sequence with chaining syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Promise implementation that works for me.

```
    function Promise(callback) {
        this._pending = [];
        this.PENDING = "pending";
        this.RESOLVED = "resolved";
        this.REJECTED = "rejected";
        this.PromiseState = this.PENDING;
        this._catch = function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        };
        setTimeout(function () {
            try {
                callback.call(this, this.resolve.bind(this), this.reject.bind(this));
            } catch (error) {
                this.reject(error);
            }
        }.bind(this), 0)
    };
    Promise.prototype.resolve = function (object) {
        if (this.PromiseState !== this.PENDING) return;
        while (this._pending.length > 0) {
            var callbacks = this._pending.shift();
            try {
                var resolve = callbacks.resolve;
                if (resolve instanceof Promise) {
                    resolve._pending = resolve._pending.concat(this._pending);
                    resolve._catch = this._catch;
                    resolve.resolve(object);
                    return resolve;
                }
                object = resolve.call(this, object);
                if (object instanceof Promise) {
                    object._pending = object._pending.concat(this._pending);
                    object._catch = this._catch;
                    return object;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                (callbacks.reject || this._catch).call(this, error);
                return;
            }
        }
        this.PromiseState = this.RESOLVED;
        return object;
    };
    Promise.prototype.reject = function (error) {
        if (this.PromiseState !== this.PENDING) return;
        this.PromiseState = this.REJECTED;
        try {
            this._catch(error);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(error, e);
        }
    };
    Promise.prototype.then = function (onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        onFulfilled = onFulfilled || function (result) {
            return result;
        };
        this._catch = onRejected || this._catch;
        this._pending.push({resolve: onFulfilled, reject: onRejected});
        return this;
    };
    Promise.prototype.catch = function (onRejected) {
        // var onFulfilled = function (result) {
        //     return result;
        // };
        this._catch = onRejected || this._catch;
        // this._pending.push({resolve: onFulfilled, reject: onRejected});
        return this;
    };
    Promise.all = function (array) {
        return new Promise(function () {
            var self = this;
            var counter = 0;
            var finishResult = [];

            function success(item, index) {
                counter++;
                finishResult[index] = item;
                if (counter >= array.length) {
                    self.resolve(finishResult);
                }
            }
            for(var i in array) {
                var item = array[i];
                if (item instanceof Promise) {
                    item.then(function (result) {
                        success(result,this);
                    }.bind(i), function (error) {
                        array.map(function (item) {
                            item.PromiseState = Promise.REJECTED
                        });
                        self._catch(error);
                    })
                } else {
                    success(item, i);
                }
            }
        });
    };
    Promise.race = function (array) {
        return new Promise(function () {
            var self = this;
            var counter = 0;
            var finishResult = [];
            array.map(function (item) {
                if (item instanceof Promise) {
                    item.then(function (result) {
                        array.map(function (item) {
                            item.PromiseState = Promise.REJECTED
                        });
                        self.resolve(result);
                    }, function (error) {
                        array.map(function (item) {
                            item.PromiseState = Promise.REJECTED
                        });
                        self._catch(error);
                    })
                } else {
                    array.map(function (item) {
                        item.PromiseState = Promise.REJECTED
                    });
                    self.resolve(item);
                }
            })
        });
    };
    Promise.resolve = function (value) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            try {
                resolve(value);
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    };
    Promise.reject = function (error) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            reject(error);
        });
    }
```

Discussing [here](https://github.com/Edeqa/Promise/blob/master/Promise.js).
Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tujger/sp8d1guv/).

Comment: The "Discussing" link points to code, not a discussion. How is this implementation better than standard Promise?

Comment: This fails core requirements of the Promises/A+ specification, namely that `.then()` returns a new promise instance with separate state. It also supports only a single rejection handler.

Answer (score -1):

here is the absolute minimum of a promise architecture

```js
function Promise(F) {
  var gotoNext = false;
  var stack = [];
  var args = [];

  var isFunction = function(f) {
    return f && {}.toString.call(f) === '[object Function]';
  };

  var getArguments = function(self, _args) {
    var SLICE = Array.prototype.slice;

    _args = SLICE.call(_args);
    _args.push(self);

    return _args;
  };

  var callNext = function() {
    var method = stack.shift();

    gotoNext = false;
    if (isFunction(method)) method.apply(null, args);
  };

  var resolve = [(function loop() {
    if (stack.length) setTimeout(loop, 0);
    if (gotoNext) callNext();
  })];

  this.return = function() {
    gotoNext = true;
    args = getArguments(this, arguments);
    if(resolve.length) resolve.shift()();

    return this;
  };

  this.then = function(fn) {
    if (isFunction(fn)) stack.push(fn);

    return this;
  };

  return this.then(F).return();
}


// --- below is a working implementation --- //

var bar = function(p) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("1");
    p.return(2);
  }, 1000);
};

var foo = function(num, p) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(num);
    p.return(++num);
  }, 1000);
};

new Promise(bar)
  .then(foo)
  .then(foo)
  .then(foo);
```