# Why use setTimeout in deferred

Tags: javascript, deferred

I tried to understand of how deferred works,so in all of them they use `setTimeout`.

```
this.callbacks;// array of functions reference
this.callbacks.forEach(function(callback){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
          callback(data);
    },0);
});
```

one example from [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722683/865477) that use `setTimeout`

```
resolve: function (data) {
    this.promise.okCallbacks.forEach(function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        callback(data)
      }, 0);
    });
  },
```

What is the different between calling functions in loop by `setTimeout` than `callback();` or `callback.call();`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason for doing this is to allow the javascript thread an opportunity to trigger any other events that may be waiting in the queue.

Javascript is single-threaded. If an event is triggered, it can only run when the currently running code has finished.

Using `setTimeout` with a zero time delay effectively tells the JS interpreter that the `callback` function call is part of a new context and that your current code block is finished. This means that JS will take the opportunity before calling `callback()` to check to see if any other events need to be handled.

Although this may delay `callback()` itself from being called immediately, this can be good for your site's overall performance:

Other events that may need to be handled include click events and other UI triggers. If you don't give them a chance to execute, it may make your user interface appear sluggish or non-responsive.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` runs after the time has elapsed *and* the JavaScript process is free.

Using `call` would run the callback immediately and block everything else.

Comment: @Moein7tl: Actually there is a lower bound to the timeout, which is greater than 0 (IIRC it's something like 4 msec for popular browsers). Hence 0 means "as soon as you can get round to it". Presumably people who use a zero timeout know about this and do it on purpose.

Comment: @Moein7tl — Yes, note that after I said "time has elapsed" I said **"and"**.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout(func,0)` is not called immediately.

Simply it simulate an asynchronous function with a callback.

```
function asyncFunc(callback) {
    console.log("step1");
    setTimeout(callback,0);
    console.log("step2");
}

asyncFunc(function() {console.log("async step")});
/* output:
step1
step2
async step
*/
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

> Code executed by setTimeout() is run in a separate execution context to the function from which it was called

So it runs in a separate execution context, but before execute it, javascript should end the current execution due javascript running on single-thread.

It doesn't matter how much time during current execution, because it MUST end before execute another task.

if you have a infinite loop before the end of task, for example, your callback never be called.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout()` allow you to register a function to be invoked once after a specified amount of time has elapsed.

The `setTimeout()` method of the Window object schedules a function to run after a
specified number of milliseconds elapses. `setTimeout()` returns a value that can be
passed to `clearTimeout()` to cancel the execution of the scheduled function.

If you call `setTimeout()` with a time of 0 ms, the function you specify is not invoked
right away. Instead, it is placed on a queue to be invoked “as soon as possible” after
any currently pending event handlers finish running.