# JavaScript promise confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm trying to grasp the concept of javascript promise. But I'm getting some problems. I set up a very small web service locally(don't get angry, the web service does not conform to conventions). Here some details about it

`/login/<username>/<password>` ==> login into the system, the correct username and password is both noor

if user is login, a call can be made on `/car/<brand>/<color>/<plate_number>`,

I'm not performing any validation on the type of color,brand,platenumber

This one works perfectly fine, I'm logging and adding a car

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",url: url+"/login/noor/noor"})
                .then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {console.log("login success");},function(){console.log("login error");})
                .then($.ajax({type: "GET",url: url+"/car/1/1/1"}))
                .then(function(){console.log("car added");},function(){console.log("car not added");});
```

This one perfectly shows an error because an invalid url is used:

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",url: url+"/carasdsad/1/1/1"})
                .then(function(){console.log("car added");},function(){console.log("car not added");});
```

"/carasdsad/1/1/1" is an invalid url and **car not added** is returned

I'm getting a problem with this one. The code below uses the code just above. I was expecting **car not added** to be shown but its showing **car added**

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",url: url+"/login/noor/noor"})
                .then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {console.log("login success");},function(){console.log("login error");})
                .then($.ajax({type: "GET",url: url+"/carasdsad/1/1/1"}))
                .then(function(){console.log("car added");},function(){console.log("car not added");});
```

The above code is returning  **car added** although **"/carasdsad/1/1/1"** is an invalid url in the second call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [spec](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/#point-24), non-function argument is ignored in `then` method.

Your code reduced to minimal case looks like that:

```
Promise.resolve(true)
    .then(Promise.reject("some err"))
    .catch(console.log.bind(console, "fail"));
```

And one need to rewrite it this way in order to catch errors:

```
Promise.resolve(true)
    .then(function(){ return Promise.reject("some err") })
    .catch(console.log.bind(console, "fail"));
```

Comment: Somehow I still think this wouldn't happen with a real promise library like BlueBird :-)

Comment: What do you mean under _real_ library? Yes, jQuery are not following A+ spec, but I tested my example with native Promises in Chrome.

Comment: Nonetheless, [deferred.then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) expects functions as arguments.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Well, Bluebird behaves the same, but it logs a warning about this rookie mistake of passing a promise instead of a callback :-)

Answer (score 0):

### a simple implement of Promise

(please use Chrome/Firefox)

```
function mPromise(executor) {
this.status = null;
this.result = null;
that=this;
executor(function(result) {
    that.status = "fullfiled";
    that.result = result;
}, function(result) {
    that.status = "rejected";
    that.result = result;
})};

mPromise.prototype.then = function(f, r) {
if (this.status == "fullfiled") {
    f(this.result);
} else {
    r(this.result);
}}
```

First,create a Promise object:

```
var a = new mPromise(function(fFlagFun, rFlagFun) {
setTimeout(function() { //using setTimeout mimic remote request
    fFlagFun("yes"); //here you can try rFlagFun("no") by hand;
}, 3000);});
```

Then **After 3s**,perform these code snippet:

```
a.then(function(e) {console.log(e);}, function(e) {console.log(e);})
```

**It may fails if you test it in other forms.** I hope the code above will give you an overview of Promise concept.

Comment: This is not only wrong, but also rather answers the question [How is a promise/defer library implemented?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17718673/1048572) than this one.