# Deferred/promise confusion and implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

If I would like to implement deferred by myself, would it be a right way to do(trying to understand the internal logic):

Does deferred counts as a behavioural pattern?

What is the difference between deferred and promise?

```
function Deferred() {
    var d = {},
        f = {},
        a = {}, 
        state = 'pending';

    return {
        resolve: function(){
            state = 'resolved';
            a.fn.apply(a.context, arguments);
            d.fn.apply(d.context, arguments);
        },

        reject:  function(){
            state = 'rejected';
            a.fn.apply(a.context, arguments);
            f.fn.apply(f.context, arguments);
        },

        done: function(fn, context) {
            d = {fn: fn, context: context};
            return this;
        },

        fail: function(fn, context) {
            f = {fn:fn, context: context};
            return this;
        },

        always: function(fn, context) {
            a = {fn:fn, context: context};
            return this;
        },

        state: state
    }
}
```

Application example:

```
var obj = Deferred();
    obj.done(function(arg){
        console.log('we are done here. why? -', arg);
    }, window)
     .always(function(arg){
        console.log('print that in any case. and some details:', arg);
    }, window)
     .fail(function(arg){
        console.log('we failed here. why? -', arg);
    }), window;


    obj.reject('some arguments');
    obj.resolve({argument: 'hooray!'});
```

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801283/what-are-the-differences-between-deferred-promise-and-future-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I would like to implement deferred by myself, would this be a right way to do?

No, your code misses a few important points:

- A promise/deferred represents one single outcome only. It's state must not be changed after it is settled (fulfilled or rejected).
- No matter when a callback is installed, it will be executed as soon as possible with the result. Your code fails to do that when the result has already arrived.
- No matter how many callbacks are installed, they all will be executed. Your code allows to store only a single callback.

You might want to have a look at [this example implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668353/1048572) or [How is a promise/defer library implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17718673/1048572).

Also, for a promise you will want to implement an interoperable `then` method for chaining, whose behaviour is described in the [Promises/A+ specification](http://promisesaplus.com/).

> Does deferred counts as a behavioural pattern?

Yeah, you could count them as a mix of observer or visitor pattern.

> What is the difference between deferred and promise?

In general, a deferred does provide the methods to fulfill or reject, while a promise is the interface to install the callbacks on (without the ability to resolve the promise). See [What are the differences between Deferred, Promise and Future in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6801283/1048572) for details.

Comment: You answered all my questions. Thanks!