# Promise lose custom function

Tags: javascript, promise, cancellation

here is a code example:

```js
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve("resolved");
});


promise.abort = function () {
  console.log("abort!");
};

console.log(promise.abort());

function bar() {
  return promise.then((value) => {
    return value + "!";
  });
}

newPromise = bar();
newPromise.then(value => {
  console.log(value);
})


console.log(newPromise.abort());
```

i added a custom function to a promise. call the function `abort()` works like expected.
in the function `bar()` i use the `then()` method to log out the resolved value.
i know that the return value of `bar()` is a new promise. but it loses the custom function `abort()`.

how can i inheritance the custom function to the new promise?

Comment: A promise should not have a method for aborting it. Put it somewhere separate, and call that function directly - not on the promise, and definitely not on descendant promises. What would you expect `promise.then(_ => timeout(500)).abort()` to do?

Answer (score 2):

Create your own class and [subclass the native Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#sub_classing_with_extends). Then you can keep custom methods as `.then()` will return the custom class

```js
class MyPromise extends Promise {
  abort() {
    console.log("abort!");
  }
}

var promise = new MyPromise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve("resolved");
});

console.log(promise.abort());

function bar() {
  return promise.then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  });
}

newPromise = bar();

console.log(newPromise.abort());
```

Comment: is there an old fashion way without `extend`?

Comment: The "old fashioned way" would probably be to implement your own promise from scratch, instead of simply extending an existing one. See [How is a promise/defer library implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17718673), [Concept - Distilling how a promise works?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15668075), and [Basic Javascript promise implementation attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23772801) for pointers. But I wouldn't recommend it. Using `extend` is the correct way to add behaviour to built-ins.

Comment: @JuKe It is impossible to (properly) subclass (ES6) builtins like `Promise` without ES6 `class` syntax

Answer (score 1):

[You cannot cancel/abort a Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233302/promise-is-it-possible-to-force-cancel-a-promise). One approach is to write a generic `timeout` or similar function to handle a long withstanding Promise -

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

function timeout(p, ms) {
  const orFail = sleep(ms).then(_ => { throw Error("timeout") })
  return Promise.race([ p, orFail ])
}

async function testTask(value) {
  await sleep(3000)
  return value
}

timeout(testTask("hello"), 5000)
  .then(console.log, console.error) // "hello"
  
timeout(testTask("world"), 1000)
  .then(console.log, console.error) // Error "timeout"
```

Another approach is to use a third-party library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html) that supports cancellation -

```js
import { Promise } from "bluebird"

function makeCancellableRequest(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject, onCancel) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.on("load", resolve);
        xhr.on("error", reject);
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send(null);
        // Note the onCancel argument only exists if cancellation has been enabled!
        onCancel(function() {
            xhr.abort();
        });
    });
}
```