# How can one access an unknown executer function from a Promise instance's construction time?

Tags: javascript, function, promise, interceptor, method-modifier

Is it possible to retrieve the implementation details of a Promise instance? Let's assume the following created promise ...

```
let myPromise = new Promise(function (success, error) {
  /* implementation */
}
```

Can one somehow access the anonymous function ...

```
function (success, error) {
  /* implementation */
}
```

... or get the location of the anonymous function in the code file?

Comment: Not when you create it like that, but you can always declare the callback function separately, with a name you can access freely.

Comment: Well, that sucks! There is a script where the devs use this concept to pass data around to basically  make reversing the code more difficult. There is a promise somewhere delivering some "intersting data" but I cant figure out where that promise is set up to see how the data is assembled.

Comment: @user2276094 sounds like an antipattern. How can there be a promise *somewhere*?

Comment: The code is heavily obfuscated and its hard to figure out where the promise is set up. There are around 100 promises created at different locations in the code.

Comment: You're trying to reverse-engineer third-party code?

Comment: Maybe the folks at [reverseengineering.se] can help

Comment: Yep. I want to figure out how they are doing what they are doing basically. Its my personal project, not work related. But it caught my interest now that it became a challenge for me

Comment: Probably more relevant than reverse engineering it: [How is a promise/defer library implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17718673)

Comment: Do you have control of the script and when it is loaded? You could potentially declare your own `Promise` class ahead of time and get the script to call it instead.

Comment: @user2276094 ... The OP might have a look at a later provided answer which provides an approach that even could solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The promise object does not contain the code, neither internally nor accessible to JavaScript. A promise represents the **result** of a task, not the task itself, it is **not runnable**. The function is used only during construction.

Answer (score 2):

What the OP tries to achieve can be done by patching the global `Proxy` function before any other code starts using it.

The next provided example code, for demonstration purposes, stretches an overwriting and function-wrapping interception and introspection approach as far as one can go.

One has to do three things ...

- reassign the `Promise` constructor function with a proxied version of itself, where the invocation of its internal `[[Construct]]` slot gets handled by custom code.
- wrap intercepting custom code around the `Promise` constructor's `executer` function.
- wrap intercepting custom code around the `executer` function's `resolve` function.

Having access to the `Proxy` constructor's `executer` function and logging it, as well as having access to the arguments passed to the `resolve` function might reveal some of the `executer` function's implementation details, thus being possibly able to provide some hints about where to drill down next.

```js
// - The actual use case, an asynchronously implemented
//   `wait` functions which resolves after the provided
//   amount of milliseconds.
// - It uses the proxied version of the before created
//   and reassigned global `Proxy` constructor function.

async function waitForResolvedData(valueInMSec) {
  console.log('... executing ...\n\n');

  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, valueInMSec, { foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar'})
  );
}

(async () => {
  console.log('waiting ...');

  const data = await waitForResolvedData(3000);

  console.log('\n... awaited data ...', data);
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>

// - reassign the `Promise` constructor function
//   with a proxied version of itself, where the
//   invocation of its internal `[[Construct]]`
//   slot gets handled.

window.Promise = (Promise => {

  const handlers = {
    construct(target, [executer]) {

      console.log(
        `\`${ target.name }\` creation with following \`executer\` function ...\n`, executer
      );

      // - wrap intercepting custom code around the
      //   `Promise` constructor's `executer` function.
      executer = (proceed => {

        return ((/*resolve, reject*/...args) => {
          let [ resolve, reject ] = args;

          // - wrap intercepting custom code around the
          //   `executer` function's `resolve` function.
          resolve = (proceed => {
            return ((...args) => {

              console.log('`\nresolve` function intercepted with following args ...\n', args);
              console.log('original `resolve` function ...\n', proceed);

              proceed(...args);
            });
          })(resolve);

          console.log('`executer` intercepted with following args ...\n', args);
          console.log('original `executer` function ...\n', proceed);

          proceed(resolve, reject);
        });
      })(executer);

      return new target(executer);
    },
  };  
  return new Proxy(Promise, handlers);

})(window.Promise);

</script>
```