# Using thunk to conditionally perform async does not execute twice

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, thunk

I'm following along with the [Kyle Simpson Rethinking Asynchronous JavaScript](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/rethinking-async-js/?u=cef6bd5cd10d4b3e7d9b80889cdee572b74cc151) video course and am confused about how his thunk pattern is using closures. The code is like this:

```
function ajax(url, cb) {
  $.ajax({ url: `text/${url}`, type: 'GET', dataType: 'json' })
  .done(data => {
    cb(data)
  })
}

function getFile(file) {
  var text, fn;
  ajax(file,function(response){
    if (fn) {
      fn(response)
    } else {
      text = response
    }
  })
  return function th(cb) {
    if (text) {
      cb(text)
    } else {
      fn = cb
    }
  }
}

var th1 = getFile('1')
var th2 = getFile('2')
var th3 = getFile('3')

th1(function ready(text){
  console.log(text)
  th2(function ready(text){
    console.log(text)
    th3(function ready(text){
      console.log(text)
      th2(function (text) {
        console.log(text)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

I added the extra call to `th2` in the final nested portion. I expected this use of closures to return the value originally printed from `th2`, stored in the closure variable `text` in the `getFile` function, ie not make another network call. Though that is not what happens: execution stops after printing the text in the `t3` callback.

#### Why doesn't this closure return its already retrieved value?

Comment: Those thunks look like poor man's promises. I wonder why he threw away the jQuery promise he already had.

Comment: @Bergi he did not use jquery. i threw that in there so i could quickly verify what was happening in the network panel. he originally had a `fake_ajax` method that used a timeout.

Comment: @bergi And he uses these thunks as part of the progression toward talking about promises.

Answer (score 0):

> I expected this use of closures to return the value originally printed from `th2`, stored in the closure variable `text` in the `getFile` function. Though that is not what happens: execution stops after printing the text in the `t3` callback.

The problem with these thunks is that you cannot use them twice (at least, when the first use is asynchronous). The value is never stored in the closure variable `text`. Why? Because `th2` was run the first time before the ajax call succeeded, which ran

```
if (text) // still empty
  …
else // nope, nothing yet, store for later
 fn = cb
```

Then later, when `ajax` calls the callback, it will only run

```
if (fn) // we got something to call
  fn(response)
…
```

and not `text = response`. So when `th2` is called a second time later (or, worse, immediately from within the callback), it will again just try to store the `cb` in the `fn` variable, but nothing will call that.

---

A possible workaround would be to do

```
… // in the thunk closure
ajax(file, function(response) {
  text = response;
  if (fn) {
    fn(response)
  }
})
```

instead which would make your code work, but still be broken: what if `th2` is called multiple times before the asynchronous `ajax` callback? Then `cb` overwrites the previous `fn`, so ultimately we would need to maintain an array of callbacks that all should get called. Well, do that and add chainability for the callbacks, and [you've got the most basic Promise implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668353/1048572) already.

Comment: I don't follow why `text = response` within the callback doesn't work. _Because th2 was run the first time before the ajax call succeeded, which ran `fn=cb`_ : Wy would `fn = cb` be run the first time?

Comment: @1252748 Because there's no `text` yet, so it stores the function. You are calling the returned `th` function for the first time before the `ajax` succeeds. (Notice that it would work if getting file 2 was faster than getting file 1 - urgh, async is hard)

Comment: It is hard but it's clear you've thunk about it an awful lot.