# Javascript, Promise.then return values

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, es6-promise

Doing some research about `Promises` and I know that a `Promise` object can be in three states (pending, resolved, rejected). The logic responsible for each of these three states is in a callback function which gets passed into the `Promise` constructor. This callback function has 2 functions as its arguments resolve and reject which are called when this callback either results in success or failure.

After the `Promise` is instantiated we can then add response handler callbacks to the promise by calling the `.then` function on it. The `.then` function takes 2 callback functions as its arguments. The first argument is the callback function is called in case the `Promise` resolve function is called and the second callback is called in case the `Promise` reject function is called. You can also call `.catch` on `Promises` to handle the rejected promises although this is just syntactic sugar for:

```
.then(undefined, () => { failure callback})
```

What I find harder to understand is the fact that the `.then` [method returns a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)  `Promise`. For example in the following code:

### Example

```js
let random = (Math.random() * 10);

let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  if (random >= 5) {
    res(random);
  }

  rej(random);
});



promise
  .then(
    (nr) => {
      console.log("succes: " + nr);
      return nr + 5;
    })
  .then((nr) => {
    console.log(nr);
  })
  .catch(
    (nr) => {
      console.log("failure: " + nr);
    })
```

### Question:

In the example at the first `.then` it returns : `nr + 5`. In resolve cases of the `Promise` this value is succesfully passed onto the second `.then`. How is this possible? Is it under the hood:

```
return new Promise((res,rej) => {
    res(nr + 5)
})
```

or is this caused by something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the behaviour of a promise, it is described here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

In Return value section:

> if the handler function returns a value, the promise returned by `then`
>   gets resolved with the returned value as its value;

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this one of [major features of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572): they are chainable.

The `then` method does return a new promise that will be *resolved with the result of the callback*. It does indeed construct a `new Promise` and does call `resolve` with the return value when the callback will be called.

You might want to take a look at [this toy implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668353/1048572) to see how it is implemented (without the error handling, though).

Answer (score 3):

**Look at this:** [Promises chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)

> Normally, a value returned by a .then handler is immediately passed to the next handler. But there’s an exception.
>
> If the returned value is a promise, then the further execution is suspended until it settles. After that, the result of that promise is given to the next .then handler.

Basically, when you return a value, i.e: `(nr + 5) or 5 or [1, 2] or {a: 1}`, Etc., that value is passed immediately to the next handler (.then).