# How the promise.then mechanisem works?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

After watching the video, and reading in [Promise.then][1] i still don't understand how it works.
So i wrote an example, and printed to console **but** still with the output i can't understand how does it work.
I hope  my question are clear enough, if not please tell me and i will try to elaborate them according to your responses.
This is my code:

```
   const getCountryData = function (country) {

   fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${country}`)
     .then(response => {
       console.log('111111111111111');
       if (!response.ok)
         throw new Error(`Country not found (${response.status})`);
       return response.json();
       })
     .then(data => {
         console.log('22222222222');
        const neighbour = data[0].borders[0];
       if (!neighbour) return;
       return fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${neighbour}`);
     })
     .then(response => {
         console.log('333333333')
       if (!response.ok)
         throw new Error(`Country not found (${response.status})`);
       return response.json();
        })
     .then(data => console.log('44444444444'))
     .catch(err => {
       console.error(`${err} `);
     })
     .finally(() => {
       console.log('finalyyyy')
     });
     
     console.log("after all async calls");
 };
```

I can't understand the following things:

1. If we look for example on the first **then**, it gets a callback as a parameter, the callback returns a *Promise* object. Which object calls the second **then**? The one that was returned from the first call to *when* or the one that have been returned from the callback?
2. I understand that the callback is "attached" to the fetch function. e.g when the fetch function will be finished, the callback will be executed. **But** i can't understand how and when the second, third and fourth **then** are called. The first callback contains also an async function ** response.json()**, so how and when exactly the **second** *when* will be started if he need the *json.response* from the first *when*?
3. If an exception occur at the first or second, how exactly the code *knows* to jump to **catch** function?
   [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: "*Which object calls the second then?*" - no "object" is calling it. *Your code* is calling the method, on an object - and in your code that is the promise returned by the first `.then()` call. "*the one that have been returned from the callback?*" - the callback was not yet executed when the second `.then()` is called, so it can't be the return value

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining

Comment: I read both links and still can't understand some stuff. 1.Do all `when` methods are executed immediately without to wait the callback to be run first?  2. How one callback returned value is the second one callback input (not exactly since it takes the values  out of the 'Promise')?

Comment: @Eitanos30 Yes, `then()` calls, promise creation, and chaining happens immediately, without waiting for anything. They just install handlers. Later, when the promise settles, the callbacks are executed, and may resolve further promises, which cause their callbacks to be executed and so on.

Comment: @Eitanos30 For understanding how promises "unwrap" (rather, how inner promise results are used to resolve outer promises), maybe have a look at [the implementation of `then`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668353/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi, thanks i really tried but this link is to hard for me now :(  thanks again

Comment: @Eitanos30 What exactly is left unclear?

Comment: "*how exactly the code knows to jump to catch function?*" - code doesn't jump. A rejection handler (as installed by `.catch()`) is called when the promise is rejected. And on a `.then()`, the result promise is rejected if the input promise gets rejected, so the error simply propagates down the chain step by step - no jumping.

Comment: @Bergi, if first throw statement happens, what exactly happens in the second and third when's callback? And in addition i'm breaking my head to understand how the callback "knows" to run only after the promise was settled (is it part of `Promise` mechanism) ?

Comment: Yes, it's part of the promise mechanism. A promise is like a one-time event emitter in that regard - when you resolve/reject it the handlers that were registered are called back.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for the help.. It's really difficult to me. I can't understand what is the type of the argument in the `then` callback method? Is it the type of the return statement of the previous `then` callback? Because in my example `response.json` return a `Promise` object, but in the following `then` it is written *const neighbour = data[0].borders[0];*, but *Promise* object doesn't have an array of data... So how is it possible?  Do you want me to open a new  post for this question?

Comment: It is the value that the promise is fulfilled with, which *generally* what was passed to the promise's `resolve()` function. And that depends on how the promise was constructed. If it's a promise constructed by (returned from) a `.then(res => …)` call, yes, it's resolved with the return value of the callback. However, [resolving means that promises are recursively unwrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269515/1048572), so if you return a promise from the `then` callback the outer promise will eventually fulfill with the inner promise's *result*.

Comment: @Bergi, so how does `const neighbour = data[0].borders[0]` is valid if data is of `Promise` type? i read in the documentation  that  `Respons.json` returns a `Promise` object

Comment: No, `data` is not a promise, it's the result of that promise.

Comment: but you said :`If it's a promise constructed by (returned from) a .then(res => …) call, yes, it's resolved with the return value of the callback`. and the first `then` returns a **response.json();** which is **Promise**, doesn't it means that the callback parameter (named `data` in the example) of  the `second then` is from the **response.json();** (which is Promise)?

Comment: Resolving is not the same as fulfilling. When you resolve with a promise, you ultimately fulfill with the fulfillment value of that promise (once it fulfills). A promise can never be fulfilled with another promise, and a `then` callback is never called with a promise.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you very much. Unfortunately it still doesn't feel that you refer to my last question. I don't want to make  you too nervous and i really appreciate your huge effort. So Unfortunately i will live without the understanding.. I'm apologize for not being clever enough. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The `then` functions don't receive a callback, they receive the result of the previous async operation.
So the result of the `fetch` is passed to the first `then`, the result of `response.json()` is passed to the second `then` and so on...

In case of error the chain broke and it goes directly to the firs `catch` function.

Under the hood there are more, consider that the fetch and other operations in the `then` functions can be asynchronous, so what happens in the runtime is that the result of the fetch function is pushed in the event queue and when the event loop takes your next then function is extracted from the queue and passed to the function.
This article explain how it works internally: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-event-loop-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-in-javascript

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP never considered `data` or `response` to be callback functions.

Comment: I think this answer is a little bit misleading. `then` does register a callback, which is later called by the underlying scheduler when the `promise` resolves. The response isn't passed to `then` but to the registered callback

Comment: @sinanspd yes, ok, I was trying to simplify. In practice what happens is that the output of the first `then` in passed to the second `then`.

Comment: @ema Yes, it doesn't work like that, but the OP never assumed it either so your answer doesn't need to point it that `then` functions don't receive callbacks.

Answer (score -1):

I will try to explain this in a different way, using `async/await` operators.

The equivalent of your `getCountryData` function is as follows

```
const getCountryData = async (country) => {
    console.log("after all async calls"); // explanation for the this line below
    try {
        let response1 = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${country}`);

        // first then
        console.log('111111111111111');
        if (!response1.ok)
            throw new Error(`Country not found (${response1.status})`);
        let data1 = await response1.json();

        // second then
        console.log('22222222222');
        const neighbour = data1[0].borders[0];
        let response2;
        if (neighbour)
            response2 = await fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${neighbour}`);

        // third then
        console.log('333333333');
        if (!response2.ok)
            throw new Error(`Country not found (${response2.status})`);
        let data2 = await response2.json();

        // fourth then
        console.log('44444444444');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`${err} `);
    } finally {
        console.log('finalyyyy');
    }
}
```

First of all, you will see the `console.log` in your last line of function became the first line in my  function. This is because the line is executed before the asynchronous function `fetch` completes.

As you can see, the last return variable from the `fetch` is available in the first `then`, and the last return variable from the `then` is available in the next `then`.

1. So for your first question, who calls the callback function in the next `then`? Obviously you can see from the `async/await` equivalent of your function, it is executed in sequence. The return result from the previous `then` will be the argument for the next `then`. Therefore in the second `then`, when you do `return;`, it will not stop executing the third `then`, but instead the third `then` will reveive `undefined` as the `response` argument.
2. As explained in answer to question 1, the `then` functions are executed in sequence automatically as long as there are no unhandled errors or rejected promise. However, for a second/third/forth `then` callback function to access the argument from the first `then`, it is not possible to access directly, unless you pass it along with every return from the subsequent `then`. This can be achieved easily by using then `async/await` operators instead of `then`.
3. How exactly does the code knows to jump to the catch function when an error is thrown? In an asynchronous function, throwing an error is almost equivalent to rejecting a promise. Think of it this way, every `then` callbacks are wrapped in a `try/catch` block that would call the function in the `catch`.

**Edit:** If you do `fetch().then().then().catch()`, all the errors or rejected promises will be handled in the catch function.
But if you do `fetch().catch().then().then()`, only the error or rejected promise from `fetch` will be handled in the catch function.

Comment: thanks but i can't understand what the callback returns. If the line ` let data1 = await response1.json();` returns a `Promise` object so how the line `const neighbour = data1[0].borders[0];` works? `data` variable is from `Promise` type, and `Promise` doesn't have `data` property

Comment: Explaining `then` in terms of `async`/`await` is mixing things up, as `await` desugars back to `then` calls.

Comment: "*for a second then callback, it is not possible to access the argument from the first then directly*" - unless you [simply nest them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/1048572), which is exactly what `await` does internally

Comment: "*It doesn't matter if you do `fetch().then().then().catch()` or `fetch().catch().then().then()`, they will work the same*" - no, absolutely not.

Comment: @Eitanos30 the `await` keyword will wait for the Promise to resolve and the result from the promise will be assigned to the variable `data1`

Comment: @Bergi I don't agree with the usage of nesting `then` because it will just create more confusion with too many nesting. I do prefer using `await` instead of `then` for promises because it is much easier to read and understand. Thank you for the correction too, the position of `catch` does matter after all after I did a simple experiment with it.

Comment: @mylee, Can you please explain me something. the `response1.json()` that is assign to `data1`, is from `Response` type.. So how does data[] works?

Comment: @Eitanos30 `response1.json()` returns a `Promise`, and the `await` keyword is important here. Take for example the code `var data = await new Promise(resolve => resolve("my data"));`, which you can run it in the console to verify, the type for the variable `data` is string, not promise.

Comment: does `await` or `then` takes the result out from the `Promise`? i still can't figure it out

Comment: @Eitanos30 a simple answer is yes